# javascript: array of objects within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

This is the sample data:

```
var data = [
    {row: 0, col: 0, value: [{x: 1, y: 19}, {x: 2, y: 20}]},
    {row: 0, col: 1, value: [{x: 1, y: 24}, {x: 2, y: 27}]},
    {row: 1, col: 1, value: [{x: 1, y: 31}, {x: 2, y: 26}]},
    {row: 1, col: 2, value: [{x: 1, y: 29}, {x: 2, y: 19}]},
]
```

I cannot figure out a way of defining x-domain.

```
var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.value.x; }))
        .rangeRoundBands([0, chartW], 0.1);
```

This bit gives error:

```
 .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.value.x; }))
```

How can I iterate through the inner array of values object ??

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Its best that you manipulate the data that you have into d3friendly format data.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK Does it mean to rearrange my data in a simpler format ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316866/d3js-getting-a-line-chart-drawn-from-json-data-input-using-d3-json
I had to change my data to a d3friendly data format,where the d3 inbuilt functions can easily recognize.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK Thanks for that! But is there no way of doing it with the format that I have above?? I really want my data to be formatted like above.

Comment: Yeh,you can by writing a code for changing your current format of the data.
I would suggest you go for the d3friendly format,cuz there are lotta d3inbulit functions you will require later on.

Comment: Take a look through https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery
You might find your required output,and compare the data input given there and change your data format to that.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK I'll have a look at the examples. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sure and do tell me if you could implement it,i am studying d3 as well.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK will let u know of how it goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have two nested iterations here:

```
.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(d) { return d3.min(d.value, function(e) { return e.x; }); }),
  d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.value, function(e) { return e.x; }); })
  ]);
```

Similarly for `y`.